# Can git be integrated with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, integration

Is there any way to use a git repository with the built in SCM functions of Xcode?

Comment: May be official soon hopefully?: http://twitter.com/pjhyett/status/15685549082

Comment: Xcode 4 is in beta (no open download yet) and has Git support built in.

Comment: @Kendall: While the Xcode 4 Developer Preview is still not a general download, it is now available to all paid developer accounts.

Comment: Since Xcode4 GM is out already this Thread should be updated...

Comment: For the record: XCode 4 is now out and free to users of OSX Lion

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Xcode 4 supports git natively (Developer Tools State of the Union Address at WWDC 2010)

Learn more here: [What's new in Xcode 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#version-editor)
The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html) from Apple is lengthy, but a good read.

Comment: That's awesome to hear.  Any word on Mercurial (hg) support?

Comment: it doesn't appear so... no word on a plugin system.

Comment: :D This made my day! Can't wait.

Comment: OMGEEZ! I had no idea...This makes me very happy...any word on release date?

Comment: Doc link is broken

Answer (score 73):

***NOTE:*** despite all the up-votes, this answer is out of date as of June 2010

---

There's no git support *within* Xcode, but that's no reason not to use git for your Xcode projects. I've had good results managing my Xcode projects using the standard git command line or [GitX](http://wiki.github.com/pieter/gitx).

Shane Vitarana has a nice set of `.gitignore` [settings](http://shanesbrain.net/2008/7/9/using-xcode-with-git) to use as a starting point.

Comment: Adding these two to my .gitignore causes broken xcode build for clones.

Answer (score 39):

A nice way to "Integrate" git with Xcode is to use [DTerm](http://www.decimus.net/dterm.php).  You bring up DTerm in a floating window with a key combination.  DTerm knows the full path to the current document in the editor.

For Example to run a diff on the file you are editing you:

1) Press Ctrl-Return to bring up the DTerm window.  (This key combo is configurable).

2) type 'git diff cmd-shift-V'.  That will overwrite the last command when you start typing and insert the name of the current file in the window.  Since your working directory is set to the parent directory of the selected file the command is nice and short.

I have no connection at all with Decimus. I am just a satisfied user who has run thousands of commands through DTerm.

**Edit**: As of 27 August 2009 DTerm is free. If you bought your copy of DTerm, the upgrade to the next version is free, regardless of when you purchased DTerm.  See their [blog post](http://www.decimus.net/support.php?path=DTerm/dterm-free)

**Edit 2**: [DTerm](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dterm/id415520058?mt=12) is now available on the Mac App Store. It will be interesting to see if they kept the promise that they made in their [blog post.](http://www.decimus.net/support.php?path=DTerm/dterm-free)

Comment: Mark - you have no idea how happy you have made me. I cannot believe I've been living without DTerm all this time!

Comment: I ran into a small thing: it is cmd-shift-V rather than ctrl-shift-V.

Comment: Dterm is **absolutely** amazing!!! -- when it works. It's very buggy with their latest version and 10.6.6 latest. I would kill to have this working right!

Comment: Try deleting the preferences file. I have had no problems with it. I have been using it for a long time. Is your login using English as the language and character input?

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the .gitignore settings referenced from the post above I have added the generated files to my config file.

build/ 
*.pyc 
*~.nib/ 
*.pbxuser 
*.perspective 
*.perspectivev3 
*.xcworkspace/ 
xcuserdata/

This helps to keep the noise out of my depot.

If I need to add generated files I add a Release folder and keep the *.framework and *.app folders to my project directory.  I add anything I release to the testing group to the Release folder and tag it.

Answer (score 10):

No, there's not, and to be honest I'm rather grateful, as the SVN support in Xcode seemed really flaky to me. After I moved to Git for my personal projects, I just have a Terminal window open that I can fire off `git add` and `git commit` as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode doesn't have a public plug-in API, so no, there's no way to directly add support for git to Xcode.

You can, however, create scripts for Xcode's script menu that can perform various git operations.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is this thing called git-cvsserver that lets git pretend it's CVS. But I don't know the state of affairs concerning that, or CVS support in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a way to provide plug-in support for Xcode.  So, until Apple warms up to git, we'll be stuck with 3rd party tools and the command line.  Not that that's a bad thing...

Answer (score 3):

The latest Xcode 4 beta has git integration, however, it does not install it by default, neither does it use your currently installed git.

What I had to do was install the "System Tools" option in the Xcode installer. (Which is skipped by default) after that, the organizer recognized that my project was already under git control, and integrated smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 4 if you want to use your own version of Git you can create a symlink from /usr/bin/git to wherever you have installed your Git binary

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Xcode 4.1 it's definitely possible and everything you need is installed by default.

I wrote a blog post just about this very topic:

[Xcode iPhone beginner projects with GitHub integration](http://www.leniel.net/2011/08/xcode-iphone-beginner-projects-git.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xcode with Git repos. [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) offers [free, private, and unlimited Git repos](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/version-control-vs) in the cloud. Not only can you use Xcode, but also Eclipse, Visual Studio, Team Services' own web browser interface, or any other editor/IDE you like. Share code with the first 5 users for free too.

YouTube video: https://youtu.be/S83kn0i4WYs

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering, if a wrapper can be done using Xcode scripting features ?
check : http://www.cimgf.com/category/version-control/git/

BTW, if Xcode can not do the job, eclipse can do the job but it may lack Cocoa api etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I use external editors anyway. Many of them support git commands. In this way, git is "integrated" into Xcode

Comment: can you give an example of external editors with git integration on mac?