# Xcode + GitHub. What is the proper setup

Tags: iphone, xcode, git

I am moving from years of Eclipse + CDT + Subclipse to Xcode with GitHub as my replacement for Subversion. I am new to GitHub and have not found a good howto for setting up a repository that knows how to play nice with and Xcode project.

Can someone please walk me through the setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this question: [Can git be integrated with Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456403/can-git-be-integrated-with-xcode)