# Reverting to last commit in Xcode 4 using Git

Tags: iphone, git

We just moved over to Git from SVN.  In trying to clean up some unused files.  I saved before deleting one folder that I thought we weren't using.  I did not push this to the origin.  I realized we are using one of the files in the folder after all, and would like to revert to my last commit.  This is on my own branch from the master.  I can't find a way to do that in Xcode.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see here for rsanchezsaez answer: [Xcode 4 git integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302367/xcode-4-git-integration)

> **Xcode 4 won't let you to checkout older commits within the user interface, unless you created a new branch for that commit.** Nevertheless, you can do it from the command line. For that, use the following command from your project folder
>
> **$ git log --format=oneline**
>
> to get the hash code of the commit you want to go to, and then use:
>
> **$ git checkout desired-hash-code**
>
> to checkout that particular version. Once there, you can make tests, changes, and possibly create a new branch. If you do a commit without creating a new branch, you will lose the newer commits in your current branch. If you want to go back to the newest commit after having performed some tests on your older version use:
>
> **$ git checkout master**
>
> note again that this won't work if you do a new commit from your old code version without creating a new branch, because newer commits in the current branch get dereferenced.

Also, please consider searching SO before asking. Many questions had already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, run a program called `gitk` - this will allow you to visualize the commits you currently have. Find the ID of the commit you want (e.g. the previous commit) and do the following on your branch:

```
git tag JustInCase
git reset --hard <commit ID>
```

Refresh `gitk`, and if you're happy with the results then delete the tag using:

```
git tag -d JustInCase
```

If you're not happy with it, just do:

```
git reset --hard JustInCase
git tag -d JustInCase
```

To visualize this for you:

1) Start

[image]

2) After tagging and resetting your branch to the previous commit.

[image]

3) After deleting the tag and doing `Reload` in `gitk`.

[image]