# Non-project files in Xcode git repository

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

This is an organizational question for iOS and OSX developers.

When you are using the automatically generated git repository for an Xcode project, how do you add/commit your non-project files such as PSDs or other third-party tool files that are the "source" for the image and audio resources?  Do you add them using the git command line, or do you prefer to maintain a separate repo for these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use the command line, but now use a GUI, to add them where they make sense in git, for example a "Source Images" folder for psd files, but I do not check in any generated files (i.e. PNG files generated from the PSDs.)

My git GUI app du-jour is [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to add the files.

I also add a custom .gitignore to all of my repos and check it in as well, but that is a [different discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456403/can-git-be-integrated-with-xcode/484275#484275).

I feel that having separate repos makes it easier to make mistakes and lose important changes, since you do not need to cd to a different repo and run the git commands there.