# Using dropbox as local Git working repo

Tags: git, github, dropbox

I have a Github repo that I use for a specific project.
I now want to work on this project at a client's office where I am unable to use git.

I was thinking about using dropbox as a local repo, pulling to dropbox from github on my home machine, using the dropbox code at work, and then pushing any changes again from home.

Has anyone done this before? I have seen lots of people using dropbox as a repo for git, but not as a single-user local working copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done exactly that and it works fine. I've also done this on a thumb drive and an external USB drive without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance. Do you have any suggestions as far as the ignore file? I am mainly worried about propagating dropbox specific files into the project. Where dropbox conflicting versions ever an issue?

Comment: I've never had any Dropbox housekeeping files show up in my git repos. Dropbox does a good job of keeping everybody in sync. You shouldn't have any issues as long as you don't edit the same file in both places before letting Dropbox sync.

Comment: As far as the ignore file goes you can see my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456403/can-git-be-integrated-with-xcode/484275#484275 I have updated this answer for Xcode4.

Comment: The cool thing about git is if any stray files show up in your repo, they probably won't match anything in your .gitignore file so they will be flagged automatically when you do a 'git status'.

Comment: That is a very good point that I had not considered. Thanks again.

Comment: I have personally been using full working copy git repos in dropbox to sync work and home computers for several years without incident.  When I leave work dropbox has completed the sync by the time I get home and then vice versa in the morning.  I've never done anything fancy like bundles.  Of course if anything goes horribly wrong I always have my actual origin server to "git" everything back to normal.